# Why does pythonw not load a flask webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, windows-10

I have created a flask app inside another python script. I want this script to run in the background? I use pythonw to execute this. The script runs in the background but the webpage does not load here. Any clues on this?

Code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
b_len = 5
b_filled = 0
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("index page starts")
    ID_List=[]
    
    b_empty = b_len - b_filled
    for i in range(0,b_len):
        if(b_empty ! = 0):
            b_empty = b_len - b_filled 
            b_filled += 1
            break
    return render_template('index.html',b_len = b_length, b_emp = b_empty, buf_filled = b_filled)
    
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Any errors you can share? And what do you mean by "does not load"?

Comment: I get the error- site cannot be reached. This occurs when i run the script using pythonw. Is there any other way the python script can be run in the background without the command prompt being visible(on windows)?